# Is there a way to increase the shader node limit?

Tags: shader-nodes

I'm curently working on a reasonably bigger shader node tree. The problem I have is that I keep hitting the shader node limit in EEVEE, so I switched to Cycles.
However after adding a few nodes even Cycles hit the node limit.

It is absolutely impossible to toss out any nodes, or "find a more elegant way to solve my underlying problem" as every node serves it's own purpose and has been optimized as much as possible, so finding a way to increase the node limit would be the only solution.

The thing is that the node tree isn't even computationally that expensive (it takes about 10 seconds to render 100 samples on a flat plane) so I absoluetly see no reason why Blender would stop me from using more nodes.

Is there a way to increase the shader node limit or remove it entirely?
And how is it calculated in the first place?

Comment: You need _a lot_ of nodes to hit the limit (>400) - at some point over this, blender encounters a SVM (Support Vector Machine) stack error and shows nothing but black. As far as I know this is a hard-coded limitation, and there is no way to increase it.

Comment: I use multiple uber shaders which can do lots of things simulatenously but consequently also have to be complicated. Is there not even a python way or something to increase the limit? @ChristopherBennett

Comment: This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) there is probably a more elegant way to solve your underlying objective

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I edited the question to make the question clearer. It doesn't seem like teh XY Problem to me though.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett If possible, could you please tell us a little more about the SVM (Support Vector Machine) (even if it isn't directly related to the question)?

Comment: SVM stands for Shader Virtual Machine as far as I know

Comment: My bad - I assumed it was doing lots of vector math. It seems _Shader Virtual Machine_ is correct as Duarte mentioned. It's just a small virtual machine that runs shader code - but it does have a buffer limit - I assume you are reaching it somehow.